# How to start discussion of a question in chat?

Tags: support, chat

I recently answer a question [Parse the json string : receiving from a java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900335/parse-the-json-string-receiving-from-a-java-code/). After like 6 comments of discussion he commented with a link to chat -

Comment - "[Let us continue this discussion in chat.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72427/discussion-between-suhail-gupta-and-aniket-thakur)"

Question with answer is listed at the top with comments on the answer as our previous chat.

> How do we do that?

Next I have been on chat before.

> So why I did not get a notification for this?

I see RSS feed icon at the top left. But I don't see any subscribe neither did I receive any message on my mail.

> Is their a way to get such chat notifications (Enable/Disable) on mail?

Comment: Do you mean to say that you expected to see a notification in your inbox when the user requested to continue the conversation in chat, but you did not, and thus you were unaware of the request? Or do you mean to say that the notification appeared in your inbox but you were not notified via email?

Comment: Actually all. But I really do not care about being notified by email. I want to know how we can move question comments to chat and why I did not get notification for the same at the notification bar. Reason being I would never know the chat unless I go to chat room.

Comment: Hm, I think you will have to be clearer, unfortunately. [I get notifications in my inbox when chat requests are made on a question.](http://i.snag.gy/KqMXw.jpg) In general, inbox notifications aren't sent to your *email* unless you haven't looked at the inbox on the site for a certain amount of time. The "let's chat" link itself, afaict, automatically shows up after a certain number of comments, although moderators have the ability to convert comments to chat whenever they want.

Comment: how is it not clear what he's asking HOW DO WE DO THAT "Let us continue this discussion in chat." THING ??? IT'S A SIMPLE QUESTION YOU SIMPLETONS. and I'd like an answer.

Comment: This is the answer for the first question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310291

Comment: It's pity that none of the close voters left a comment.

Comment: This question is literally the first search result for "How to start a chat in StackOverflow", and it is closed, with an answer late in the comments. I've voted to re-open it, but in the meantime, it sounds like you don't start a chat room for a question, but you can start a chat with an individual from their profile, as mentioned here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310291/notify-others-users-to-join-the-chat-room-for-discussion