# Notify others users to join the chat room for discussion

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat

Why doesn't Stack Overflow provide a **feature** which can invite other users to a chat room?

I know that if there are too many comments but the problem still not yet solved, we can move the discussion to chat in order to make the page clean. However, some of the discussion  might not come out with a solution. Would it be better if the user can notify other users that are online to join the chat? Of course users can  accept or decline the invitation.

Comment: Which other users? How would they be invited?

Comment: users in stack overflow

Comment: That's a very large group of people, how is that going to be filtered down? Unless you're suggesting the ability to invite literally every user to chat to discuss the comments on a single post...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This already exists. You just navigate to their chat profile and invite them. This profile can be found by going to the subdomain chat. Yours is https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5398173/john and if I wanted to invite you I would simply click here

[image]

Once in the room, there is also a link to invite.

The user's reputation needs to be 20 to have chat privilege.